# Comparing 2 different rows in Power Query Editor

Tags: excel, powerquery

I need help creating a custom column that tells me how many days it takes for a document to get from `REVIEWED` to `APPROVED`. The `NUMBER` column is unique but in order to compare I need to also filter out the documents that do not have both the `REVIEWED` and `APPROVED` Stamp.

The way the data comes in there is a possibility for their to be more than one `REVIEWED` stamp, i'm only concerned with the most recent one.

[image: DATA]

Comment: You could just add a formula column to your table.

Comment: This is in Power Query Editor so it's not a table nor do normal Excel formula functions work. I need help creating coding for the custom column

Comment: It'll probably be easier if you unpivot your `STAMP` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most efficient, as I am pretty new with PQ.

But one way to do this is with multiple tables.

- Filter Table where STAMP = APPROVED
- Create another filtered table where STAMP = REVIEWED
- Group "reviewed table" by NUMBER with operation = MAX to get last reviewed date
- Combine the Approved and Last Reviewed table
- Add a  custom column calculating the difference between the reviewed and approved date
- Add the Duration column back to the original table.

Note that I added some rows in the table to allow for multiple review dates.

You can see that in the results.

#### M-Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"NUMBER", type text}, {"STAMP", type text}, {"STAMP DATE", type date}, {"STAMP MONTH", type text}, {"STAMP YEAR", Int64.Type}}),
    
            approved = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([STAMP] = "APPROVED")),
            reviewed = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type",each ([STAMP] = "REVIEWED")),
            lastReview = Table.Group(reviewed, {"NUMBER"}, {{"lastREVIEW", each List.Max([STAMP DATE]), type date}}),
            cmbTbl = Table.AddJoinColumn(approved,"NUMBER",lastReview,"NUMBER","RevDate"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(cmbTbl, "Custom", each List.Last(Table.Column([RevDate],"lastREVIEW")) - [STAMP DATE]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"STAMP", "STAMP DATE", "STAMP MONTH", "STAMP YEAR", "RevDate"}),
    
            addDuration = Table.AddJoinColumn(#"Changed Type","NUMBER",#"Removed Columns","NUMBER","Duration"),
    #"Expanded Duration" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(addDuration, "Duration", {"Custom"}, {"Duration"})
in
    #"Expanded Duration"
```

[image]

**EDIT:** I just noticed that the `Table.ExpandTable` method has the potential to change the order from the original table.  If that might be an issue, I suggest changing the last few lines of the code to:

```
            addDuration = Table.AddJoinColumn(#"Changed Type","NUMBER",#"Removed Columns","NUMBER","comb"),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(addDuration, "Duration", each List.First(Table.Column([comb],"Custom"))),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"comb"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works fine...

Add column that picks up the last review date of each ID

Filter to get APPROVED rows that have a REVIEW date

Subtract APPROVE date from max REVIEW date for difference

Remove extra columns

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source,"MaxDate",(i)=>List.Max(Table.SelectRows(Source, each [NUMBER]=i[NUMBER] and [STAMP]="REVIEWED") [STAMP DATE]), type date ),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([STAMP] = "APPROVED") and ([MaxDate] <> null)),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Custom", each [STAMP DATE]-[MaxDate]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"MaxDate"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Custom", type number}, {"STAMP DATE", type date}})
in  #"Changed Type"
```